# PHP / jQuery ( $.post ) Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know that my code won't work doing what I want it to do because I don't know how to make it do what I want it to do.  My javascript is calling my bet_process page on click, but I need one element ( $hash ) provided prior.  I need this because providing the sha512 hash prior to the roll the user can see the hash but can't decrypt it.  After the roll is presented (decrypted) they can encrypt it to see if it matched the provided hash PRIOR to see if they aren't being cheated.  The code i'm using below is working perfectly fine, but I need to do what I have explained above.  If anything is unclear please let me know and I'll try my best to rephrase/reword.

**bet_process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db.php';
if($_SESSION['address'] == "") {
 $uid = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
    $uid_query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'"));
    $uid = $uid_query['username'];
}

$rand = rand(100, 10000)/100;
$hash = hash('sha512', $rand);
$select_gg_amt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$uid'");
$select_gg_amt2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `address` = '{$_SESSION['address']}'");
$select_gg_row = mysql_fetch_array($select_gg_amt);
$select_gg_row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select_gg_amt2);
if($_SESSION['address'] == "") {
$balance = $select_gg_row['balance'];
}
else { $balance = $select_gg_row2['balance'];
}
$amount1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['profit']);
$amount2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bet']);
$time_ago = date("F j, Y, g:i a");


    if($balance >= 0 && $_POST['chance'] >= 0.01 && $_POST['chance'] <= 98 && $_POST['bet'] >= 0 && $_POST['bet'] <= $balance) {

        if($rand < $_POST['chance']) {
            if(isset($amount1, $amount2, $_POST['chance'], $_POST['pay'])) {
            echo '<h3>You rolled a <strong>' . $rand . ' </strong> out of 100 on the percentile dice!  You won!</h3>';
            echo '- <span style="font-size: 8px;">', $hash, '</span>';

            $result = 'Win';

            if($amount2 != 0) {

            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` + '$amount1' WHERE `username` = '$uid'");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bets`(`amount`, `time_ago`, `username`, `multiplier`, `roll`, `result`) VALUES ('$amount2', '$time_ago', '$uid', '{$_POST['pay']}', '$rand', '$result')");

        }
            }

        }

        else {
            if(isset($amount1, $amount2, $_POST['chance'], $_POST['pay'])) {
            echo '<h3>You rolled a <strong>' . $rand . ' </strong>out of 100 on the percentile dice!  You lost!</h3>';
            echo '- <span style="font-size: 8px;">', $hash, '</span>';

            $result =  'Loss';

            if($amount2 != 0) {

            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` - '$amount2' WHERE `username` = '$uid'");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bets`(`amount`, `time_ago`, `username`, `multiplier`, `roll`, `result`) VALUES ('$amount2', '$time_ago', '$uid', '{$_POST['pay']}', '$rand', '$result')");
            }

        }

        }

      }


    else { echo '<h3>Your bet must be <strong>valid</strong>!</h3>'; }

?>
```

**my_script.js**

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false;    
});
```

**HTML: bet.php**

```
    <form action="bet_process.php" method="POST" id="myForm">   
  <h2 class="title">Betting Settings <span class="line"></span></h2>
 <div class="form-box">
 <label for="bet">Bet Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="bet" id="bet" class="text" placeholder="Amount" value="0">
</div>
<div class="form-box">
<label for="pay">Multiplier </label>
<input type="text" class="text" name="pay" id="pay" value="2">
</div>
<div class="form-box last">
<label for="profit">Profit </label>
<input type="text" name="profit" id="profit" class="text" placeholder="Profit" value="0">
  </div><!-- End Box -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="form-box">
<label for="chance">Win Chance (%)</label><input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="49.5" placeholder="Win % - 50.5% Default">
</div>

            <p>Slide to choose win chance or enter it in the input!</p><br><input type="range" id="chanceslider" class="vHorizon" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="98" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
</div>





 <div class="form-box">
    <input type="submit" name="start1" class="button medium color sub" value="Roll Dice" id="sub">
   </div><!-- End Box -->
<h3 id="result"></h3>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: *I know that my code won't work doing what I want it to do because I don't know how to make it do what I want it to do.* i up-voted for that sentence.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, but I'll guess the answer is that `bet.php` needs to put the hash into a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Reread the OP or ask a more specific question so I can clarify.

Comment: How much prior do you want/need `$hash`? When `bet.php` is loaded, before they 'roll', when they 'roll'?

Comment: Before they roll.  Reread OP.